# How to do automatic API relay in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a frontend express.js app and need to request to a lot of apis from client side(browser) to another server. I need to request those apis from server side and send responses to browser, due to cross domain problem. I am now writing every api as a route method in my app to receive requests and re-send recieved data as responses. Because of the number of apis is huge, and rewrite every request is prone to error and hard to maintain, I wonder whether there is an express.js way to relay all requests with their methods and parameters not changed from browser to the other server. For example, if I request to some /api/test route of my server, it should request to /test route of the other server, receive response and respond it to me.

Unfortunately there is no way to change anything of the server which implemented the apis. So I could only do this work in the express.js app.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a proxy, for which there are several prebuilt ones you can use with node.js or you can even use a standalone proxy server that you configure via a config file.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll search for some express.js proxy and try to add it to my app.